# The best fit triangle in cv2

Tags: python, opencv, convex-hull, convexity-defects

TLDR: I am looking to fit a triangle to a boomerang-shaped object in order to detect its "head", potentially using python's `opencv`.

---

I have a collection of boomerang-shape objects (see image below), whose size and internal angles vary. Additionally, sometimes the "boomerangs" (unlike a real boomerang) can be asymmetric with one leg longer than the other, and can have defects and holes along their legs.

I can accurately extract the contours of these shapes, and now am trying to detect the direction the boomerang is facing (defined as the direction the "pointy" edge, the one marked by brown dots in the image below).

My plan so far was to use `opencv`'s convex defects method to detect the internal angle, and from there detect the direction. However, my "boomerangs" are not perfect - they sometimes have holes and defects along their legs that confuse the convex defect algorithm.

My question is: is there a way to find the best-fit triangle (much like the [best fit ellipse](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html)) that would fit the boomerang?

[image: Boomerang]

Comment: maybeuseful: [minEnclosingTriangle](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga1513e72f6bbdfc370563664f71e0542f)